# How can I make multiple lines into one line using bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

So I have code that looks like this:

```
else if(between(pay,1260,1280))
{
    return 159;
}
else if(between(pay,1280,1300))
{
    return 162;
}
else if(between(pay,1300,1320))
{
    return 165;
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
else if(between(pay,1260,1280)){return 159;}
else if(between(pay,1280,1300)){return 162;}
else if(between(pay,1300,1320)){return 165;}
```

Can I do this in bash? If not, which language can I use?

The full code is over 30,000 lines and I could manually do it, but I know there's a better way. I want to say the 'sed' command can help me with a mixture of regex, but that's as far as my knowledge can take me.

P.S Please overlook how un-optimized it is just this once.

Comment: We can help you with a rule to transform what you've shown us (essentially one specific example, repeated 3 times), but it'll probably break other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following awk may also help you in same.

```
awk -v RS="" '{
$1=$1;
gsub(/ { /,"{");
gsub(/ }/,"}");
gsub(/}/,"&\n");
gsub(/ else/,"else");
sub(/\n$/,"")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
else if(between(pay,1260,1280)){return 159;}
else if(between(pay,1280,1300)){return 162;}
else if(between(pay,1300,1320)){return 165;}
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation for solution too now.

```
awk -v RS="" '{      ##Making RS(record separator) as NULL here.
$1=$1;               ##re-creating first field to remove new lines or space.
gsub(/ { /,"{");     ##globally substituting space { with only { here.
gsub(/ }/,"}");      ##globally substituting space } with only } here.
gsub(/}/,"&\n");     ##globally substituting } with } and new line here.
gsub(/ else/,"else");##globally substituting space else with only else here.
sub(/\n$/,"")        ##substituting new line at last of line with NULL.
}
1                    ##motioning 1 here as awk works on method of condition and action.
                     ##So here I am making condition as TRUE and then not mentioning any action so be default print of current line will happen.
'  Input_file
```

Comment: This was the simplest implementation. Thank you! I have no idea what any of it means, but I can't wait for the day that I do know.

Comment: @Francisco, Added explanation successfully to my code now, please go through it and let me know if you have any queries on same.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^else/{:a;N;/^}/M!ba;s/\n\s*//g}' file
```

Gather up the required lines in the pattern space and remove all newlines and following spaces on encountering the end marker i.e. a line beginning `}`.